# How to Mock Service class while writing a Junit for Spring-ws endpoint

Tags: junit, mockito, spring-test, spring-ws

I have created a Spring SOAP based webservice which retrives data from my DB , I am able to test the service through SOAP UI , but now I am trying to add few functionalites for the service and I want to add some Junits for the service , Please find my Endpoint and Junit details below.

### My End Point Class

```
@Endpoint
public class CountryEndPoint {
    private static final String NAMESPACE_URI = "http://tutorialspoint/schemas";

    @Autowired
    CountryRepository countryRepository;


    @PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "getCountryRequest")
    @ResponsePayload
    public GetCountryResponse getCountry(@RequestPayload GetCountryRequest request) throws JDOMException {

        Country country = countryRepository.findCountry(request.getName());
        GetCountryResponse response = new GetCountryResponse();
        response.setCountry(country);
        return response;
    }
}
```

### Spring-context.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:sws="http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans

   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services/web-services-2.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan
        base-package="com.tutorialspoint" />
    <sws:annotation-driven />

    <bean id="schema"
        class="org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource">
        <constructor-arg index="0" value="*.xsd" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

### Junit-Test calss

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "/spring-context.xml")
public class CustomerEndPointTest {
    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;
    @Autowired
    private ResourceLoader resourceLoader;
    private MockWebServiceClient mockClient;
    private Resource schema = new ClassPathResource("countries.xsd");

    @Before
    public void createClient() {
        mockClient = MockWebServiceClient.createClient(applicationContext);
        GenericApplicationContext ctx = (GenericApplicationContext) applicationContext;
        final XmlBeanDefinitionReader definitionReader = new XmlBeanDefinitionReader(ctx);
        definitionReader.setValidationMode(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.VALIDATION_NONE);
        definitionReader.setNamespaceAware(true);
    }

    @Test
    public void testCountryEndpoint() throws Exception {
        Resource request = resourceLoader.getResource("request.xml");
        Resource response = resourceLoader.getResource("response.xml"); 

mockClient.sendRequest(withPayload(request)).
andExpect(payload(response)).
andExpect(validPayload(schema));
    }
}
```

I am able to run the test case with out any issue but my problem is I am not able to mock my service class (CountryRepository) mock the the code below.

```
Country country = countryRepository.findCountry(request.getName());
```

Does any one have any suggessions on this?

Comment: So, you want to mock the CountryRepository object, am I right?

Answer (score 0):

From your test case, I suppose your are trying to mock the `CrudRepository` object from inside a webservice call: That would be called integration testing. You need to make a choice for unit testing:

1. Test the request, and assert its response http status code (for example),
2. Or test the `getCountry` method inside your `CountryEndPoint` class. Doing both options at the same time would be considered an integration test.

I will try to answer considering the unit test case, using option 2. I think it will give you better insights for the future.

You are injecting the dependency of the `CountryRepository` on your `CountryEndPoint` class. You need to do the same on your testing class. For example, a basic setup would be:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "/spring-context.xml")
public class CustomerEndPointTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private CountryEndPoint countryEndPoint;

    @Mock
    private CountryRepository countryRepository;

    @Test
    public void testCountryEndpoint() throws Exception {
        Mockito.when(countryRepository //...
        countryEndPoint.getCountry(request //build a request object and pass it here.
        //assertions...
    }
}
```

Then, whenever a method from `CountryRepository` is invoked, it will be invoked from the mock instead. This is only possibly because of the injection of the mock via annotations.

If you actually send a request, using a HTTP client (like you intended), you cannot mock the methods being invoked inside your controller class, because you are not manipulating and assigning the instances yourself, and thus are not able to determine what is a mock, and what is not.